# Is the React Fragment Type Wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

look at the type definition of React, I find the ReactFragment type is below

```
type ReactFragment = {} | ReactNodeArray;
```

we know that {} in Typescript means interface with no members and {} can represent any types such as string, number, object, function except null and undefined, I want to ask that do you think this is wrong with React Team, if not, why?

Comment: Yes, this is an issue that is discussed [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/29307) and [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34530).